# C#: Double array to NAudio wavestream to play as a looped sample?

Tags: c#, arrays, audio, synthesizer, sound-synthesis

An example of what I'm trying to do is this: https://youtu.be/rSRJ4VIoP-A?t=176

Here's an example of an array that I want to play through the speakers as an audio waveform oscillator, a centered sinc function on an array of 256 items.
[image]

I'm familiar with making sine waves, which is a continuous function plotted on an array of an indefinite length. For example, on NAudio (https://markheath.net/post/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio):

The question is, how can you replace the sine code with the contents of the specified array?

```
public class SineWaveProvider32 : WaveProvider32
{
    int sample;

    public SineWaveProvider32()
    {
        Frequency = 1000;
        Amplitude = 0.25f; // let's not hurt our ears
    }

    public float Frequency { get; set; }
    public float Amplitude { get; set; }

    public override int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)
    {
        int sampleRate = WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        for (int n = 0; n < sampleCount; n++)
        {
            buffer[n+offset] = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency) / sampleRate)); //this is the line that does the sine wave. I'm trying to replace it with a specified array to use as a sample
            sample++;
            if (sample >= sampleRate) sample = 0;
        }
        return sampleCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RawSourceWaveStream.md ?

Comment: I tried, but it gave either errors or the wrong audio